# Removing Column Header using JSLink

Tags: 2013, jslink

I know this is probably an easy thing, but I'm not finding it anywhere (my GoogleFu isn't up to par, I guess). I'm trying to remove column headers in a list when reformatting using JSLink. We are currently using SP2013.

Basically, I have a list with two columns. One column stores a URL, while the other column stores the description (or what is displayed as the hyperlink). When all is said and done, I only want the hyperlink to be displayed. At this point, I'm able to display what I want using the following code, but I don't know how to turn off the headings:

```
(function () {

var overrideCtx = {};
overrideCtx.Templates = {};
overrideCtx.Templates.Fields = {

'URL': { 'View': quickLinks },
'Title': { 'View': quickLinks2 }

};

SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);

}) ();

function quickLinks(ctx) {

    var urllink = ctx.CurrentItem.URL;
    var urldesc = ctx.CurrentItem.Title;
    var appeldLink = "<a href=" + urllink + ">" + urldesc + "</a>";

    return appendLink;

}

function quickLinks2(ctx) {

    var urldesc2 = "";

    return urldesc2;

}
```

I'm sure what I'm asking to do is uber easy ... I'm just not finding it. What can I add to the above code to remove the column headers? (**NOTE:** The above code is working just fine to display what I need. I'm just looking to be rid of the column headers.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a Header Template you can use to override the header:

```
overrideCtx.Templates.Header = function(ctx) {return "--"};
```

This plugin may help you: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cisar/nifbdojdggkboiifaklkamfpjcmgafpo?hl=en

Comment: Thanks Omar. I will try this tomorrow when I get back to work.

Comment: This worked, however, it removed my formatting below the headers, stacking all of my hyperlinks in a single line. Also, the return of two dashes ["--"] didn't fit either. To overcome these two things, I added a <br> in the quickLinks function and removed the dashes. This gave me what I needed.